# Iterate through a list of strings In SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How do you access the value within a list in T-SQL?

I have a SQL statement that loops through and counts how many times a value appears in a specific column in `Table_1`. Then it inserts the required values into their columns on `Table_2` or if the row dose not exist, it adds a new row and adds the necessary data.

I created the list or table to be exact,

```
DECLARE @MyList TABLE (Value NVARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Data1')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Data2')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Data3')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Data4')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Data5')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Data6')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Data7')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Data8')
```

The statement works fine, but I have everything hardcoded and I want to add some dynamic data to be inserted, so I created a list of values (Strings). Now I can't access the values the way I though I could.

This is the whole statement,

```
DECLARE @cnt INT = 1;
DECLARE @MyList TABLE (Value NVARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Data1')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Data2')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Data3')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Data4')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Data5')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Data6')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Data7')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Data8')

                        WHILE @cnt < 9
                        BEGIN

                            IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Staff_Manager.dbo.Staff_Count_TBL WHERE Staff_No = 3201 AND Year_D = 2016 AND Month_D = 6 AND Column_Index = @cnt)
                                BEGIN
                                  UPDATE Staff_Manager.dbo.Staff_Count_TBL 
                                            SET Column_Value = (
                                                 SELECT COUNT(*)  
                                                 FROM Staff_Manager.dbo.Staff_Time_TBL
                                                 WHERE Staff_No = 3201 AND Date_Data BETWEEN '2016/6/1' AND '2016/7/1' AND Info_Data = 'Data_1'
                                                 GROUP BY Staff_No, Info_Data),
                                                 Column_Value2 = 'Data1'
                                                 WHERE Staff_No = 3201 AND Year_D = 2016 AND Month_D = 6 AND Column_Index = @cnt
                                END
                            ELSE
                                BEGIN
                                   INSERT INTO Staff_Manager.dbo.Staff_Count_TBL 
                                        (Staff_No, Year_D, Month_D, Column_Index, Column_Value, Column_Value2)
                                        SELECT 3201, 2016, 6, @cnt, COUNT(*), 'Data1' 
                                             FROM Staff_Manager.dbo.Staff_Time_TBL
                                             WHERE Staff_No = 3201 AND Date_Data BETWEEN '2016/6/1' AND '2016/7/1' AND Info_Data = 'Data1' 
                                             GROUP BY Staff_No, Info_Data
                                END
                            SET @cnt = @cnt + 1
                        END
```

What I am trying to achieve is to loop through a list that has 8 items in it and enter those values into their corrosponding columns.

Eg,

On this line I have hardcoded `Data1`,

```
WHERE Staff_No = 3201 AND Date_Data 
       BETWEEN '2016/6/1' AND '2016/7/1' AND Info_Data = 'Data1'
```

What I am trying to do is this,

```
WHERE Staff_No = 3201 AND Date_Data 
       BETWEEN '2016/6/1' AND '2016/7/1' AND Info_Data = @MyList[@cnt]
```

And this,

```
SELECT 3201, 2016, 6, @cnt, COUNT(*), @MyList[@cnt] 
                     FROM Staff_Manager.dbo.Staff_Time_TBL                           
                     WHERE Staff_No = 3201 AND Date_Data 
                    BETWEEN '2016/6/1' AND '2016/7/1' AND Info_Data = @MyList[@cnt]
```

But that does not work. After researching a little more, I found that T-SQL does not actually make a list , but a temp Table so to speak and you need to get the value from there. Unfortunately I can't seem to get anything to work.

I have an `UPDATE` and a `INSERT` statement that I need to add the value from the list.

EDIT: Last minute code tweaking,

```
DECLARE @cnt INT = 1;
DECLARE @MyList TABLE (Value NVARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Data1')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Data2')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Data3')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Data4')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Data5')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Data6')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Data7')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Data8') 
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Data9')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Data10')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Data11')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Data12')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Data13')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Data14')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Data15')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Data16')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Data17')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Data18')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Data19')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Data20')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Data21')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Data22')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Data23')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Data24')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Data25')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Data26')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Data27')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Data28')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Data29')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Data30')

DECLARE @COUNTER INT = 0;
DECLARE @MAX INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @MyList)
DECLARE @VALUE VARCHAR(50);


                        WHILE @cnt <= @MAX  
                        BEGIN
                        SET @VALUE = (SELECT Value FROM @MyList 
                            ORDER BY 1 OFFSET @COUNTER 
                            ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY);


                            PRINT @cnt
                            PRINT @VALUE
                            PRINT @COUNTER

                            IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Staff_Manager.dbo.Staff_Count_TBL WHERE Staff_No = 3005 AND Year_D = 2016 AND Month_D = 6 AND Column_Index = @cnt)
                                BEGIN
                                  UPDATE Staff_Manager.dbo.Staff_Count_TBL 
                                            SET Column_Value = (
                                                 SELECT COUNT(*)  
                                                 FROM Staff_Manager.dbo.Staff_Time_TBL
                                                 WHERE Staff_No = 3005 AND Date_Data BETWEEN '2016/6/1' AND '2016/7/1' AND Info_Data = @value
                                                 GROUP BY Staff_No, Info_Data),
                                                 Column_Value2 = @value
                                                 WHERE Staff_No = 3005 AND Year_D = 2016 AND Month_D = 6 AND Column_Index = @cnt
                                END
                            ELSE
                                BEGIN
                                   INSERT INTO Staff_Manager.dbo.Staff_Count_TBL 
                                        (Staff_No, Year_D, Month_D, Column_Index, Column_Value, Column_Value2)
                                        SELECT 3005, 2016, 6, @cnt, COUNT(*), @value 
                                             FROM Staff_Manager.dbo.Staff_Time_TBL
                                             WHERE Staff_No = 3005 AND Date_Data BETWEEN '2016/6/1' AND '2016/7/1' AND Info_Data = @value 
                                             GROUP BY Staff_No, Info_Data
                                END
                            SET @cnt = @cnt + 1
                            SET @COUNTER = @COUNTER + 1
                        END
```

Comment: Am I correct that you are inserting same values eight times? The only difference is `column_index`.

Comment: @IvanStarostin, When `column_index = 1` then 'Info_Data = Data1` , `column_index = 2` then 'Info_Data = Data2` and so on through the loop.

Comment: Well, you don't have this algorithm in your code. Is this `@MyList` variable - from your real code or you are obtaining data to be insterted somehow else? If it is then how are you determining which row from @MyList belongs to which column? You don't have nor `identity` neither `col_index` column in `@MyList` so values are not linked to any _position_.

Comment: @Yes it is the actual code, of coarse, it is not working. So I should add an `index` of some sort to keep track of the position?

Comment: And after adding that `col_index` - have another look on your code. Does not this "loop" look like a regular join? `on col_index=col_index`, `set Column_Value2 = data`

Answer (score 58, accepted):

What you created is not a list but a table variable. So how to Iterate over a table. Below is a simple example and I think you can proceed after if you understand it:

**(Note: Cursors are not efficient when it comes to performance and large tables)**

```
DECLARE @MyList TABLE (Value NVARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Data1')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Data2')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Data3')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Data4')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Data5')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Data6')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Data7')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Data8')

DECLARE @value VARCHAR(50)

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT Value FROM @MyList
OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @value   

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   
       PRINT @value

       -- PUT YOUR LOGIC HERE
       -- MAKE USE OR VARIABLE @value wich is Data1, Data2, etc...

       FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @value   
END   

CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

**Prints:**

```
Data1
Data2
Data3
Data4
Data5
Data6
Data7
Data8
```

So you have inside @value variable `Data`, `Data2` .. etc . I think this solves your problem.

### Alternative way is using a `WHILE` loop + `OFFSET` + `FETCH NEXT` :

```
DECLARE @MyList TABLE (Value NVARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Data1')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Data2')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Data3')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Data4')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Data5')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Data6')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Data7')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Data8')

DECLARE @COUNTER INT = 0;
DECLARE @MAX INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @MyList)
DECLARE @VALUE VARCHAR(50);

WHILE @COUNTER < @MAX
BEGIN

SET @VALUE = (SELECT VALUE FROM
      (SELECT (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))) [index] , Value from @MyList) R 
       ORDER BY R.[index] OFFSET @COUNTER 
       ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY);

PRINT @VALUE

SET @COUNTER = @COUNTER + 1

END
```

You get the same result

Comment: OK, so how do I put it in as a value in a column, Ie, This is hard coded `Info_Data = Data1` , I want the data from the table when looping through, `Info_Data = @MyList[@cnt`

Comment: @KyloRen `@value` variable is the same as `@MyList[@cnt]` that you want.

Comment: Ahh, I see what you did. You put the value into `@Value`. Will it always loop through in order of the table list?

Comment: Thanks, that has solved the issue. The second set of code is what I got working thanks again. UV for the help and nice answer.

Comment: OK, we have a problem Houston. The `@Value` does not iterate though the table list in order. It jumps all over the place. Why would this happen?

Comment: Is your table exactly like in your question or do you have other columns ?

Comment: All I did was increase the number of values in `@MyList` from 8 set's of data to 30 set's of data. Would that change anything?

Comment: @KyloRen it should not change anything, can you post the code you're using at the end of your question ?

Comment: Done, really appreciate this very much.

Comment: @KyloRen the first method guarantees the order. The second method doesn't because there should be an order by clause in that syntax. If you want to use the second method, we'll need to add more logic to keep the items in order. Please let me know if you need it.

Comment: The problem with the first method is that it is outside the loop and is always just the first value `Data1`. How do you get it to iterate through the table `@MyList`

Comment: @KyloRen I'll fix the second in a minute. Be aware you're using `cnt` and `counter`, you should have only one and it should start from 0 and not 1. Please be aware of that.

Comment: @KyloRen check the updated query in the second method, now it preserves the order. Hope it works. But please, use only `@COUNTER` without your old `cnt` and start it from 1 and not 0 or you'll miss the first element.

Comment: Just a note - If you run that SP again it will give error as the Cursor declared globally. Use LOCAL after cursor declaration (`CURSOR LOCAL FOR`) to avoid that error only if you need it locally.

Comment: if anyone wonders what `order by (select NULL)` means: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10066840/2866644

Answer (score 4):

not with this specific code, but in general if you need data from a list of unique values in ascending (or descending) order, you don't need a cursor (or even a counter), you can select min/max Value from @MyList that is bigger/smaller than the last one.
for a loop without counter the code looks like this:

```
SET @VALUE = ''
WHILE (@VALUE IS NOT NULL) BEGIN
  SET @VALUE = (SELECT MIN(Value) FROM @MyList WHERE Value > @VALUE)
  IF @VALUE IS NOT NULL BEGIN
    -- code comes here
  END
END
```

if you need the data in a specific order, you can add the counter to @MyList, and have a similar query with the counter in the while and where part (works with your code, too)

```
DECLARE @MyList TABLE (Cnt INT, Value NVARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES (1, 'Data1')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES (2, 'Data2')
-- and so on

SET @cnt = (select min(Cnt) from @MyList)
WHILE (@cnt <= (select max(Cnt) from @MyList)) BEGIN
  SET @VALUE = (SELECT Value FROM @MyList WHERE Cnt = @cnt)
  -- your code comes here
  SET @cnt = @cnt + 1
END
```

Comment: `SELECT @VALUE` prevents @VALUE to be NULL thus causing an infinite loop in the first code. updated my answer to use `SET @VALUE` to allow NULL

Comment: Doesn't this cause an issue in the last iteration where @VALUE will be null since there is no more minimum values?

Comment: @AndrewRichesson very true, you need to handle NULL in the code, I updated the answer.  Also, the first answer is very generic, and does not work with the OP's code since that uses `@cnt` many ways